Using key implement Play Integrity in Android
I was using SafetyNet till now for playstore key validation but now we can't use SafetyNet. So I have made the changes in code. The issue I am facing is, I am not able test if the implementation is correct. Could any one guide me how to do the testing. Below I have written the code.
Note: The key mentioned below is splash key which is used is splash page.
String str ="BYY1Mzk3NTAxMjYbcqu2NTM5NzUwMTI5SCv=";
         byte[] strBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] encoded = android.util.Base64.encode(
                strBytes, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE | android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING | android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String nonce =  new String(encoded);   
     RootBeer rootBeer = new RootBeer(this);
        if (rootBeer.isRooted()) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        } else {
            if (rootBeer.isRootedWithBusyBoxCheck()) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            } else {
                IntegrityManager integrityManager =
                        IntegrityManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
                        == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                    Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> integrityTokenResponse =
                            integrityManager
                                    .requestIntegrityToken(
                                            IntegrityTokenRequest.builder().setNonce(nonce).build());
                    integrityTokenResponse.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<IntegrityTokenResponse>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onSuccess(IntegrityTokenResponse integrityTokenResponse) {
                                                                       });
                            integrityTokenResponse.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    });

                } else {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }}}}

I implemented the same and tested the apk but with it I am able to login which in case should fail as I used wrong splash key.

Have you linked it to a cloud (Firebase) project? Generally it is the one you are using for Crashlytics. You need send the project id (you would add it as a param when building the original request)...after you get the token you will need to decrypt. If you are 'signed by google" you should send it to Firebase for decryption, if you are not yet signed by google, you will need to create and register keys in the Play store portal and decrypt it with that key pair...the results JSON is in the token. Hope that helps. Also, don't forget to enable integrity services in the Google Cloud Services portal.
